# inserting array elements into database

Tags: php

I want to store Each element of each array into mysql database fields. how can i do that?

```
<?php

// primarily a method for storing data
// arrays are counted from 0

$hosts = array(
array("ronmexico.kainalopallo.com/", "beforename=$F_firstname%20$F_lastname&gender=$F_gender",
"Your Ron Mexico Name is ",
"/the ultimate disguise, is ([^<]+)<\/b><\/u>/s"),<u><b>([^<]+)<\/b><\/u>/s"),

array("rumandmonkey.com/widgets/toys/mormon/index.php",
"gender=$F_gender&firstname=$F_firstname&surname=$F_lastname",
"Your Mormon Name is ","/
My <p>My Mormon name is
<b>([^<]+)<\/b>!<br \/>/s")
);

return $hosts;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could `serialize` the array and insert the serialized array into the database. Then, we you pull the data out of the database, you would run `unserialize` and it will turn back into a PHP array.

More info: [PHP: serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)

Comment: but my array is the array within arrays like..host= array( array(1,2,3), array(4,5,6), array(7,8,9) );   now i want to store each and every element into different field in mysql database like 1 is one field, 2 in other field, 3 in other and so on. can u give me the code for it

Answer (score 0):

You could try building up the MySQL statement using an array if you already know a Mapping between the Array's Key-Value pairing and the MySQL's table's columns:

```
$sql = "insert into $table ";
foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
    $sql .= "set $key = $value, ";
}
$sql .= ";";
```

If you have an array structure like `array( array(1,2,3), array(4,5,6), array(7,8,9) );`

You know that `for($arr as $key => $val)` will give you something like `[1] => array(1,2,3)`

Although I don't think you would be able to save arbritrarily deep arrays using that method. If you have situations where you don't know beforehand how deep the array structure will be, or how it relates to the database, then you should probably save a serialized version like `mririgo` said.

Comment: I don't know how to map between the array's key- value pairing and the mysql's table columns

Comment: ('".serialize($yourarray)."')"; – mririgo 10 mins ago
but my array is the array within arrays like..host= array( array(1,2,3), array(4,5,6), array(7,8,9) ); now i want to store each and every element into different field in mysql database like 1 is one field, 2 in other field, 3 in other and so on. can u give me the code for it?